# ImageCropper.Forms plugin not working in Xamarin.Forms iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am using [this plugin](https://github.com/stormlion227/ImageCropper.Forms) and [ImageCropper.Forms nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ImageCropper.Forms/) for cropping images in `Xamarin.Forms`

My Android project is working fine using above example but in iOS cropping window does not open

Comment: Please add more details. Maybe you see some message in the ouput-window while debugging or some exceptions. Add the relevant code-snippet to your question. Otherwise its alomst impossible to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Believe you are using Cropper from a page pushed using 'Navigation.PushModalAsync', try 'Navigation.PushAsync'.

I've raised an issue on github
https://github.com/stormlion227/ImageCropper.Forms/issues/22