# ImageCropper.Forms is not working in ios platform (System.MissingMethodException)

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

I am using [ImageCropper.Forms](https://github.com/stormlion227/ImageCropper.Forms) package for cropping images. It is working fine on the android part but when I try it on ios, I am getting the below exception:

> Exception:>System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Plugin.Media.Abstractions.MediaFile> Plugin.Media.Abstractions.IMedia.TakePhotoAsync(Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncVoidMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine] (TStateMachine& stateMachine) [0x0002c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:84
> at Stormlion.ImageCropper.ImageCropper.Show (Xamarin.Forms.Page page, System.String imageFile) [0x00033] in <548dc893a11b47fe908c9c3d7f4a39ba>:0
> at ImageCropDemo.MainPage.OnClickedRectangle (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00002] in /Users/companyname/Downloads/ImageCropDemo/ImageCropDemo/ImageCropDemo/MainPage.xaml.cs:29

**Found the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53555554/imagecropper-forms-plugin-not-working-in-xamarin-forms-ios), but it didn't solve my problem.**

**My Code**

```
try
{
    new ImageCropper()
    {
        Success = (imageFile) =>
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                image.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(imageFile);
            });
        }
    }.Show(this);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Exception:>" + ex);
}
```

I tried to install `ImageCropper.Forms.Fix.v3` to solve this issue. When I try to install `Fix.v3` getting the below errors:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   NU1101  Unable to find package Plugin.Persmissions. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages, nuget.org    ImageCropDemo   C:\Users\user\Downloads\ImageCropDemo\ImageCropDemo\ImageCropDemo\ImageCropDemo.csproj  1=
> Error      Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'ImageCropDemo'.

The `ImageCropper.Forms.Fix.v5` installation is success, but no change in the exception. `ImageCropper.Forms.Fix.v6` and `ImageCropper.Forms.Fix.v7` packages are also available, which package will solve this issue in ios?

I have uploaded a sample [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BVdwF0MKSELaPF_Lu9l0VHGNu-xSfGb-/view?usp=sharing) for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems caused by the package itself . Here is a similar [issue](https://github.com/stormlion227/ImageCropper.Forms/issues/30) .

If you do want to implement it you could use the plugin [Xamarin.Plugin.ImageEdit](https://github.com/muak/Xamarin.Plugin.ImageEdit) to edit your image .

Install it into your forms project and each platform project.

```
public byte[] GetImageStreamAsBytes(Stream input)
    {
        var buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int read;
            while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }

    async void OpenCamera(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

            if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Alert", "No camera available.", "Ok");
                return;
            }

            _mediaFile = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
            {
                Directory = "Sample",
                Name = "test.jpg",
                AllowCropping = true,
                PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Medium
            });

            if (_mediaFile == null)
                return;
            

            using (var newImage = await CrossImageEdit.Current.CreateImageAsync(GetImageStreamAsBytes(_mediaFile.GetStream())))
            {
                var croped = await Task.Run(() =>
                        newImage.Crop(0, 0, 250, 300)
                             .Rotate(180)
                             .Resize(100, 0)
                             .ToPng()
                );


                image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(croped));
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("CameraException:>" + ex);
        }
    }
```

This plugin can only crop the image with a fix value . If you want to set the area in runtime , check the sample in the  github project site .

Comment: In my case, the camera or gallery is not opening. When I choose the option I am getting that exception. It was a nice package, is there any way to fix this issue in ios?  Xamarin.Plugin.ImageEdit is not user friendly.

Comment: You could post the issue to github issue , I had added each of fix package but all didn't work .